# Devise 1.5 + Omniauth 1.0 + Facebook: undefined method `extra`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook, devise, omniauth

I'm trying to get my Cucumber test to work with Devise 1.5 and Omniauth 1.0, with Facebook authentication. Funny thing is, it works on development mode, but when run the Cukes test, it fails with this message:

```
undefined method `extra' for #<Hash:0x007f95f0d26260> (NoMethodError)
./app/models/user.rb:13:in `find_for_facebook_oauth'
./app/controllers/users/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb:4:in `facebook'
(eval):2:in `click_link'
./features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:58:in `/^(?:|I )follow "([^"]*)"$/'
features/facebook_auth.feature:11:in `When I follow "Sign in with Facebook"'
```

Here is the corresponding method:

```
def self.find_for_facebook_oauth(access_token, signed_in_resource=nil)

    data = access_token.extra.raw_info
    if user = User.where(:email => data.email).first
        user
    else 
        User.create!(:email => data.email, :password => Devise.friendly_token[0,20]) 
    end
end
```

To get the Cukes test to be all green, I had to do this workaround, which then breaks the Development mode code. So for now, I'm doing this:

```
    case Rails.env
    when "test"
        data = access_token['extra']['user_hash']
        if user = User.find_by_email(data["email"])
            user
        else 
            User.create!(:email => data["email"], :password => Devise.friendly_token[0,20])
        end
    else
        data = access_token.extra.raw_info
        if user = User.where(:email => data.email).first
            user
        else 
            User.create!(:email => data.email, :password => Devise.friendly_token[0,20]) 
        end
    end
```

Seems like the offending line is `data = access_token.extra.raw_info`.

The way I'm mocking the Facebook hash is:

```
OmniAuth.config.add_mock(:facebook, {
    :uid => '12345',
    :nickname => 'zapnap',
    :extra => {
      :user_hash => {
        'email' => 'someone@webs.com'
      }
    }
  })
```

And I have turned on `OmniAuth.config.test_mode = true` by appending it at the last line of `test.rb`.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got exactly the same error and could somehow get it to be all green.
Although I use stub instead of mock
[as is written here](https://gist.github.com/792715), hope it can be a help.

As it is discussed [here](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/issues/558), this occurs because OmniAuth1.0 uses Hashie::Mash for the part we got error.
So, we figured out to use a Hashie::Mash object to return instead of a Hash.
In order to do so,

I added this to spec_helper..

```
require "omniauth"
```

and modified stub method like this..

```
def stub_env_for_omniauth
  request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
  pre = { "omniauth.auth" => { "provider" => "facebook", "uid" => "1234", "credentials" => {"token" => "abcdefg"}, "extra"=>{"raw_info" => {"id" => "1234567", "email" => "ghost@nobody.com", "name" => "Mark", "gender" => "male" }}}}
  env = OmniAuth::AuthHash.new(pre)
  @controller.stub!(:env).and_return(env)
end
```

This works for me.

Comment: Oops, I've just noticed that you opened the issue. Thanks for that:)

Comment: You're welcomed! I've tried to use the patch from [link](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/issues/556) but still no luck. But that's a good idea. Thank you!

Comment: how did you make this work with Cucumber tests? this seems to be rspec related ...

Answer (score 3):

You can place settings in the spec_helper.rb, as alternative to stub_env_for_omniauth method.

```
  OmniAuth.config.test_mode = true
  OmniAuth.config.full_host = 'http://example.com'

  omni_hash = {
    'uid' => '12345',
    'provider' => 'facebook',
    "info" => {
      "email" => Faker::Internet.email,
      "image" => "http://example.com/pic.img"
     },
    "extra" => {
      "raw_info" => {
        "first_name" => Faker::Name.first_name,
        "last_name" => Faker::Name.last_name,
        "name" => Faker::Internet.user_name,
        "gender" => "male",
        "locale" => "en"
      }
    }
  }
  OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:facebook] = OmniAuth::AuthHash.new(omni_hash)
```

Answer (score 1):

For Cucumber tests an additional mock object seems to work:

```
Given /^a new facebook user "([^"]*)"$/ do |name|
  OmniAuth.config.test_mode = true
  OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:facebook] = {
    :provider => 'facebook',
    :uid => '123545',
    :name => name}

  m = mock("mock_extra",
    :raw_info => 
      mock("mock_raw_info", 
        :email => 'someone@webs.com',
        :first_name => name,
        :last_name => "xyz"))

  OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:facebook].stub(:extra).and_return(m)        
end
```